# Delete a role after set time (discord.py)

Tags: python, discord

**NOTE: I am using `discord.Client` for my code.**

So, when we are sending a message, we can use `delete_after=secs` parameter to delete a message after some time.

```
channel = await message.author.create_dm()
await channel.send("test dm (deletes after 60 secs)", delete_after=60)
```

But, do we have thing like that with `discord.Role`, or is there another solution to remove a role after some time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is docs for [discord.Role.delete](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=discord%20role#discord.Role.delete).
If you look there, you can see that it is not build in, so you'd have to implement the solution yourself.

Luckly its not too bad.

```
import asyncio
...
await asyncio.sleep(delay)
await discord.Role.delete(discord.Role.id, reason=None)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Not quite what I meant, but this works too. (I wanted to remove a role from member, not delete the role)